# Best component to show three columns

Tags: dictionary, components, uicollectionview

I am struggling myself thinking about which component to use in my new app.
The first screen I am using Collection View with big images. Once the user touches one cell, it goes to the second screen ... and here is the problem.
I have three columns, similar to a dictionary with first language, second and third. The user will be able to choose which column he wants to search, and according to his criteria it will show the result that matches. I am not sure how to implement this, which component gives the best experience to the user. Any idea is more than welcome. Thank you in advance. Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is several rows each with 3 columns, I would recommend customizing a UITableView. I followed [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/) tutorial when I was trying to set up something similar.

The Table View will also give you efficiency if you have a lot of data, and you can build the custom table cells in the interface builder so that makes life a little easier.

-Ken

Comment: All examples given look great!! I will try to implement all.
Answered!!